# mySQL Error on local host but not on remote

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Don't know what I've done wrong. My script works fine on my remote host but, having exported and imported to my localhost server I am getting an error:

> 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'tbl...'.

Any suggestions would be welcome. I am guessing that my instance of MySQL is set up differently somehow but I am at a loss as to how troubleshoot it.

Comment: Please add the code snippet too

Comment: What query causes the error?

Comment: From the (limited) information provided Im guessing that your query contains table names or aliases which are not unique...

Comment: I really don't want to add the code snippet it is so messy I am embarrassed.  Anyway I works fine, as I say, it is not the code I have a problem with but my local setup of mysql.

Comment: you have to post the query not the entire code.

Comment: OK, but it won't make a lot of sence

Comment: It is too long by 1082 characters, but it is pre-processed variables building the query on the fly and as I say, this is not what my question is about.

Comment: Ok, the script looks up all many to many tables based on a primary key name and id and returns the related records on the outer join. So the query is dependent on the variables passed to it and will make no sense without the values. Sorry, I am not being obtuse I just can't provide it.

Answer (score 0):

Case sensitive on the server and insensitive on local machine would be my guess. If not, please provide a snippet of the failing command.

Comment: Good shout, I'll check.

Comment: Got it, thank you. For some reason the export is all lower case, while the original is proper case. i.e. tbl_Table_Name rather than tbl_table_name.

Comment: OK, so my local installation won't let me rename the a table other than lower case.  Any idea where the setting is to turn this on/off?

Comment: @Bri go into the ini-file. There you need to change or add an entry to enable case sensitive table names. I think it was "lower_case_tablenames = 1" under "[mysqld]". Then you need to restart the database-server before you can rename tables.

Comment: Hi DataVada, Tried that and it crashed the server on restart:

Comment: Log reads:    2018-07-04 17:07:02  12840  Note  C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete
2018-07-04 17:07:06 - Checking server status...
2018-07-04 17:07:06 - Trying to connect to MySQL...
2018-07-04 17:07:06 - Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061) (2003)
2018-07-04 17:07:06 - Assuming server is not running
2018-07-04 17:07:11 - Checking server status...
2018-07-04 17:07:11 - Trying to connect to MySQL...
2018-07-04 17:07:11 - Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061) (2003)
2018-07-04 17:07:11 - Assuming server is not running